# how to remove nulls from sql

Tags: sql

i'm trying to execute this code for filtering data

```
select 
   max(case when meta_key = 'miglad_firstname' then meta_value end) as f_name,
   max(case when meta_key = 'miglad_lastname' then meta_value end) as l_name,
   max(case when meta_key = 'miglad_country' then meta_value end) as country,
   post_id

from sw_postmeta where group by post_id  order by f_name DESC;
```

Where `post_Id` has used for grouping  data of table but problem is that it showing me so many Null field
My Column looks like this

```
post_Id  |  meta_key  | meta_value 
    3      |  miglad_firstname     | John            
    3        |  miglad_lastname       | Arya
    3        | miglad_country      | India
   4         | miglad_firstname       | Ram
   4         |   miglad_lastname      | Singh
  4          | miglad_country       | Sri Lanka
```

But result showing like this

```
 F_name  |   l_name    |   country
  John       | Arya          |  India
   Ram       |   Singh       |  Shri Lanka 
   Null        |  Null            |  Null
  Null       |  Null             | Null
  Null       |  Null             | Null
  Null       |  Null             | Null.....
```

So I want to remove these null result from sql. So How I can do this please help

Comment: does your code really work ? there's a group by just after where. it should not work. what are you trying to achieve ? is it ms sql ?

Comment: Sorry, Actually there is `miglad_firstname` in `meta_key` collumn

Comment: you'll get better help with a working example and data. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: You select 4 columns, but only 3 are returned...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `post_id` from your select query and you should get your desired result.

```
select 
   max(case when meta_key = 'miglad_firstname' then meta_value end) as f_name,
   max(case when meta_key = 'miglad_lastname' then meta_value end) as l_name,
   max(case when meta_key = 'miglad_country' then meta_value end) as country,
from sw_postmeta where group by post_id  order by f_name DESC;
```